# Cannot install APK signed by myself

Tags: android, apk

I have devolped an application for Android with minSDK=10 and targetSdk=19.

I have always test it on my Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.2), downloading the apk file or just using eclipse. Now I want to test it on some other devices like (4.1.2). So I download the apk file and start installation but a message appears saying that package installer has been stopped and my application cannot be installed.

My project is compiled against Java jdk 1.6.

Any idea to explore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you download it from?  If not GooglePlay, did you enable unknown sources in settings?  Do you have a version signed with a different (perhaps debug) certificate already installed on the device which you did not remove first?

Comment: Maybe "insufficient storage"? Try updating by Eclipse and check LogCat/console.

Comment: downloaded from my public folder of dropbox. Yes it is enabled.

Comment: not insufficient storage neither...

Comment: If you have a different version of the app installed, you will need to uninstall it. Also try installing it on another android device and see if it will install on that.

Comment: No previous installation.
It works ok from 4.3 in advance... 
4.2.2 doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to solve it. It was the dimmension of the icon image.